# Vuejs - tr row not showing 100% when adding display block

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my VuewJS application, I want to be able to click a row and show/hide the row below. However, when I do that I get a weird bug were the row below only fills one column width.

Here is my table structure:

[image]

> NOTE: This table is generated dynamically.

The top row with 4 columns has an attribute of `id` and the long row that fills up 4 columns has a a data attribute `data-body-id`.

```
<tr v-bind:key="data.id" v-bind:id="index" v-on:click="rowClick(index)">
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
</tr>
<tr v-bind:key="data.id" v-bind:data-body-id="index">
    <td colspan="4">Col 5 (This is a really long  4 colspan row ..............)</td>
</tr>
```

which computes as:

```
<tr data-v-1a25d82d="" id="0">
    <td data-v-1a25d82d="">Col 1</td>
    <td data-v-1a25d82d="">Col 2</td>
    <td data-v-1a25d82d="">Col 3</td>
    <td data-v-1a25d82d="">Col 4</td>
</tr>
<tr data-v-1a25d82d="" data-body-id="0">
    <td data-v-1a25d82d="" colspan="4">Col 5 (This is a really long  4 colspan row ..............)</td>
</tr>
```

in my `rowClick(index)` method I have:

```
methods: {
  rowClick(id) {
    var dataId = "data-body-id='" + id + "'";
    var row = document.querySelector('[' + dataId + ']');
    row.style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

When I click a row, the row below is visible but it shows like so:

[image]

If I use the developer inspector and find the attribute and uncheck the display: none; that is set in the CSS initially to hide the row it shows perfectly.

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Could you add a JSFiddle/Codepen or just insert a code snippet into your question? It might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to show dynamic table rows that are hidden please use:

```
display: 'table-row',
```

so in your case:

```
row.style.display = 'table-row';
```

Comment: I didn't even know this was a thing (im a noob). thank you.